# Economic history/geography of the UK (1960-today)

Tags: reference-request, gdp, economic-growth

I am not an economist and I am looking for reference knowledge about how the economy of the UK (mainly focussing on England/Scotland/Wales) developed over the past 5 decades. The kind of information I need concerns:

- **GDP** by **sector**: how did the different sectors change over time (e.g. decline of manufacturing and rise of services)?
- Statistical **regions**: how did they evolve? What are their commonalities/differences?
- How did different **cities** evolve (e.g. London vs Manchester/Birmingham)?
- Economic trends and **demography**: What is the relationship between economic trends and population?

What (relatively) recent textbooks/reports/articles would you recommend to find this kind of topics?

I don't necessarily need the associated data, but that would be a nice plus.